# changes in css and js in server, does not apply on website

Tags: javascript, css, server, gunicorn

I have changed some codes of css and js in server and used these commands:

`kill -HUP <pid>`

and also:

`killall -HUP gunicorn`

but changes didn't appear on website. I have deleted all caches on my browser
how should I apply changes in website?

Comment: delete all cache in your browser.   or perhaps it's just that the hosted files are cloned, I'm not familiar with gunicorn.

Comment: yes I have deleted all caches, it still does not apply

Comment: try adding version queryString to end of your files import. For example "src: somepath.css?v1"

Comment: no, I just changed width @ibrahimmyilmaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using Filezilla on ubuntu. it let me to see what directories are in website, navigate through them more efficient and change codes

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to open in a private window and clear cache. Then try to refresh with Shift+F5 which will ignore cached content.

If that doesn't work, I would suggest to use something like Inspect in Chrome and clicking on a console to show up any errors that could happen which couldn't render your changes.

HTML, CSS and JS are interpreted by your browser so you don't need to restart anything except deploying app.

Answer (score 0):

If you have cleared all  cache and still can't find the change on the Website, then there is a possibility that you may be referencing a different CSS.

Here is what to do.

1.Remove the CSS and JS files completely and see if the Website still loads fine, If it does then you know there is another CSS file somewhere.

2.Try making other changes on the CSS Document to see if it reflects,If it does reflect, then you know something is interfering with the changes, making it not appear on the website.

Comment: I will try this, it may be true

Comment: I changed some big parts but it still didn't change

Comment: What error did you get when you completely removed the CSS and JS files?